# I can't figure out why scrapy will not insert a bitcoin price into a mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy

I'm new to python scrapy.  I've done a few tutorials and I've been able to  isnert data to mongodb but it has not worked on own simple project of taking an api and putting the bitcoin price into the mongodatabase.  My scrapy project is as follows:

```
bitscrape/spiders/__init__.py
# This package will contain the spiders of your Scrapy project
#
# Please refer to the documentation for information on how to create and manage
# your spiders.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import scrapy
from bitscrape.items import BitscrapeItem

class BitcoinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bitcoin_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['coindesk.com']

    start_url = ["https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json"]
    page = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")

    def parse(self, response):
        item = BitscrapeItem()
        q = page.json()
        item["time_posted"] = q['time']['updated']
        item["price_used"] = q['bpi']['USD']['rate']
        yield item
```

Below is my items.py

```
bitscrape/items.py
import scrapy


class BitscrapeItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    time_posted = scrapy.Field()
    price_used = scrapy.Field()
    pass
```

Below is my middleware.py # I did not alter this

```
from scrapy import signals


class BitscrapeSpiderMiddleware(object):
    # Not all methods need to be defined. If a method is not defined,
    # scrapy acts as if the spider middleware does not modify the
    # passed objects.

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # This method is used by Scrapy to create your spiders.
        s = cls()
        crawler.signals.connect(s.spider_opened, signal=signals.spider_opened)
        return s

    def process_spider_input(self, response, spider):
        # Called for each response that goes through the spider
        # middleware and into the spider.

        # Should return None or raise an exception.
        return None

    def process_spider_output(self, response, result, spider):
        # Called with the results returned from the Spider, after
        # it has processed the response.

        # Must return an iterable of Request, dict or Item objects.
        for i in result:
            yield i

    def process_spider_exception(self, response, exception, spider):
        # Called when a spider or process_spider_input() method
        # (from other spider middleware) raises an exception.

        # Should return either None or an iterable of Response, dict
        # or Item objects.
        pass

    def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
        # Called with the start requests of the spider, and works
        # similarly to the process_spider_output() method, except
        # that it doesn’t have a response associated.

        # Must return only requests (not items).
        for r in start_requests:
            yield r

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        spider.logger.info('Spider opened: %s' % spider.name)
```

Below is my settings.py #these are the only changes I've made

```
    DOWNLOAD_DELAY = .25
    RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY = True

    # ...

    # Configure item pipelines
    # See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
    ITEM_PIPELINES = {
        'bitscrape.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 300,
    }
    MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    MONGO_DATABASE = 'z-bitscrape'
```

Below is my pipelines class

```
import logging
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'bitcoin_prices'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        ## pull in information from settings.py
        return cls(
            mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        ## initializing spider
        ## opening db connection
        self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        ## clean up when spider is closed
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        ## how to handle each post
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Post added to MongoDB")
        return item
```

Here is the printout from my mongod terminal:

```
2018-01-12T10:27:29.794-0600 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50138 #2 (2 connections now open)
2018-01-12T10:27:30.159-0600 I NETWORK  [conn2] end connection 127.0.0.1:50138 (1 connection now open)
```

I don't show a new database being created when I run scrapy crawal so obviously the 'bitcoin_prices' collections are not showing up because the 'z-bitscrape' database is not being created.

Finally, here is the printout from my cmd prompt window:

```
(mynews_grabber) ..\PycharmProjects\mynews_bit\bitscrape>scrapy crawl bitcoin_spider
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: bitscrape)
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'bitscrape', 'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0.25, 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bitscrape.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': [
'bitscrape.spiders']}
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['bitscrape.pipelines.MongoPipeline']
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://api.coindesk.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json>
2018-01-12 10:27:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-01-12 10:27:30 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/exception_count': 1,
 'downloader/exception_type_count/scrapy.exceptions.IgnoreRequest': 1,
 'downloader/request_bytes': 224,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 580,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 12, 16, 27, 30, 159735),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 12, 16, 27, 29, 793714)}
2018-01-12 10:27:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: First, please specify what does it mean that *it doesn't work*. Logs, traces etc. I see some discrepancies in the spider (e.g. incorrect spelling for `start_urls` attribute, superfluous use of `requests` library etc.). But regarding your problem the most important thing is to show the pipeline class, `bitscrape.pipelines.MongoPipeline`.

Comment: @TomášLinhart Hello Tomas, I added the pipelines class along with the mongod and cmd prompt terminal outputs.  Thank you for looking at this issue

Comment: See the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the provided log from Scrapy run, you are being blocked by `robots.txt`:

```
...
2018-01-12 10:27:29 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt: <GET https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json>
...
```

Therefore, Scrapy stops before even reaching `parse` method and yielding any items (thus, there's nothing to pass to the pipeline). You may try to overcome this by setting `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY=False` in your `settings.py` or `custom_settings` spider attribute.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  This was a big help!